# How to convince co-authors it is unethical to include false research citations in "working paper" being submitted to a conference?

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review, ethics, research-misconduct

I'm third co-author on a paper that was re-submitted for publication after primary author redid data analyses when I discovered that our original data had been significantly flawed.  A month or so went by, and then I simply was sent notification of the new submission, without ever notifying me, and giving me no chance to review it or suggest changes. I found changes in the wording of the Conclusions which I disagree with, and when I checked a particular citation which the first paragraph in the Conclusion section was based upon, I discovered that the citation is a gross misrepresentation of what the cited person said. The cited person has told me by email and phone that the citation is "bogus" - it is false information, and not in any way derived from her scholarship.

Here is an analogue of the citation, but I changed the name, and it is not about car drivers: "Jones (1989) reported that no medical evidence exists to indicate that one sex possesses a significant physical advantage over the other in the relevant skills necessary to be a racing car driver."

The first paragraph of the Conclusion goes like this:
"This is in spite of biological and medical evidence that indicates no readily apparent comparative advantage for male racing car drivers.  In fact, female car drivers appear to have a relative advantage over males in number of physical characteristics important for racing car driving success."

The reality is that there actually IS biological/medical evidence that males have advantages in Reaction Times and upper body strength necessary for steering under adverse circumstances.

The person who was misquoted never even mentioned racing car drivers, and told me to please remove any mention of her from the paper.

I asked the co-authors to retract the paper before it was sent out to reviewers, and they refused.  The senior author mentioned that he had cited the author in a previous publication, and that it was merely a case of unintentional "sloppy writing" - and that he would remove the citation ***after*** getting responses from the reviewers.

They did not want to be embarrassed by having to pull the paper back a ***second*** time.

I told them they were subverting the Peer Review Process by knowingly submitting Research findings which did not exist, and which were patently and provably false.

I told them that the citation obviously was one of the lynchpins of their argument that there are zero physical differences which could account for differing race results, and that the relatively poorer race outcomes for females must therefore be supporting evidence of gender bias against female racing car drivers, and that this bogus research finding might sway the reviewers in deeming their conclusion to be appear internally valid, when it was not.

They disagreed, and asserted that it was little more than a typical editorial problem which they would solve in the normal way, by making changes after the inevitable suggestions for revision from the referees.  I had pointed out a number of other problems which I had - including the absence of summary descriptive statistics of winning percentages in the Results section, and they said we could discuss all these other problems which I found later, before final submission.

They apologized for their oversight in not notifying me, asked me to be "patient" and trust that there was no malfeasance here,  offered to include me in all subsequent revisions, and suggested that I was welcome to ask to have my name removed from the paper if I still disagreed.

Soon after, the virus pandemic started, I fell ill (not from covid-19) and decided to just let the matter drop until reviewer feedback emerged.

And now, a month later, I received  copies of notifications from a virtual conference that they were presenting their "working paper" - and the working paper is exactly the same as the one they submitted to the professional journal. That paper has been sent to 8 people via CC.

No changes, the exact same FALSE claim about scientific medical evidence - which turns out to be non-existent, and actually in the opposite direction.(Note: what especially bothers me is that they cited a paper which discussed potential advantages of females regarding size and flexibility, but which also specifically mentioned male physical advantages related to reaction time and strength. They could not possibly have read the paragraph they cited without seeing the cited advantages of reaction time and strength, the reality of which they denied three times throughout the paper, but especially in the key Concluding statement).

I complained again, repeated my accusations of unethical academic misconduct, and asked them to retract the paper for proper editing. They apologized, and respectfully disagreed with my conclusions, and told me it was necessary for them to obtain addition feedback from fellow professionals in this conference, and that this was a part of the Peer Review process, that it would not look good, and that I should just be patient and Trust the Process.

I have told them that it is misconduct to disrespect the wishes of the author whose work they misrepresented, and refuse to remove her name from their paper.

I told them it is misconduct to knowingly present FALSE evidence and FALSE conclusions to a group of conference attendees who will likely just accept their authority - AND their conclusions - and who will likely share with other people the false belief that there is zero biological or medical evidence of physical advantages for males.

They disagree once again with my conclusions regarding their actions, asked for my patience, and reminded me that I can have my name removed before any final publications.

How can I convince these people who are entrusted with managing a department and teaching young students about ethical science that they have a Blind Spot regarding their own behavior?

Am I the one who is wrong about the ethics of this situation?
I have seen reports of people FIRED and careers destroyed for submitting false research data.

I did a search on Google, but can not find any websites which specifically offer me ammunition in explaining why their behavior represents misconduct and a lack of integrity.

Can anybody help, please?

Comment: Can you remove your name from the conference presentation (because it's wrong) but leave it on the paper (that will allegedly be right when it's finally published)? (It's easy for me to talk about removing your name, because I'm old enough that one publication more or less won't make much difference. I realize that you may be at a very different stage of your career, where every publication matters.)

Comment: Is the mis-cited author, Jones, aware of the unchanged "working paper" being presented at a conference? Is she aware of your effort to get it corrected?

Comment: The main issue for me is how to get these people to realize that what they  are doing is Unethical. If I send them here, and enough people say that it is misconduct to knowingly disseminate FALSE Research citations misrepresented as "evidence" then I can get my point across. Maybe. Anybody have any references to send these folks to for Remedial Research Ethics?

Comment: See https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93929 for an earlier discussion of the immorality of submitting results that one know are wrong. (That question also has a link to an earlier one.)

Comment: There is probably no answer to your question. Given their behaviour, your coauthors seem impervious to research ethics considerations. Maybe they think that their transgressions won't harm them professionnally, and maybe they are right. You cannot make a donkey drink when it is not thirsty.

Comment: I think we'll be more able to help if you can refocus the question away from "how can I convince these people they are wrong" and instead towards "what actions should I take to meet my own ethical obligations".

Comment: I'm amazed that nobody seems to be able to cite any actual documentation that knowingly submitting incorrect statements or citations in your Lit Review and Conclusions is unethical and academic misconduct.  At this rate, what is to stop these folks from saying that I am conjuring up an Urban Myth, and being hysterical....which is basically what they have said.